# Ошибка в андроид студии

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Error:Connection refused: connect

вот такую ошибку он выводит при попытки синх. градла. На компе инет работает отлично. На всякий пожарный отключил брандмауэр. Может нужно подключить в градле че то. Проект пустой только создан.
вот мои градлы:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle.app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.test.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330895/gradle-sync-failed-connection-refused

Comment: я посмотрел сайт https://services.gradle.org без впн у меня не работает. Можно как то самастоятельно скачать?

Comment: не понял, какой сайт не работает? То, что я вам скинул?

Comment: @Likhanov нет при входе в андроид студию иде download чего то по адресу https://services.gradel.org/.../..../...zip через несколька секунд выходит это ошибка.